# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.sql' when using with EMR Serverless

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm getting the following error when I'm trying to run a job on EMR serverless -

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark.sql'. Please refer to user guide on how to use python libraries with EMR Serverless.

It happens when I try to import pyspark.sql in a python file located within a zip package.

The file -

```
pyspark.zip
|--__init__.py
|--spark.py
```

The content -

```
#__init__.py
from .spark import *

#spark.py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

def run():
    print("Create Spark Session")
    spark_session = SparkSession\
        .builder\
        .appName("First pyspark project")\
        .getOrCreate()
```

The spark property I gave to the job -

> --conf spark.submit.pyFiles=s3://my-bucket/pyspark.zip

> --conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=python

I am afraid I missed something. Should I install it or something?
All I did was compress the project into a zip file and upload it to S3.

Comment: There's a good chance your "pyspark.zip" file is getting unpacked in your path and conflicting with the actual "pyspark" namespace. Try either changing the name of the zip or just putting your code in spark.py and uploading that. There's also no need to set the PYSPARK_PYTHON variable.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too. The spark property you gave to the job is incorrect.

For EMR, it should be:

```
spark.yarn.dist.pyFiles=s3://my-bucket/pyspark.zip
```